# MySQL error code: 1064 during CREATE TABLE in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Trying to create a table in MySQL workbench and I keep getting this error message "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7"

Here is what I have input...what am I doing wrong?

```
create table members (
id varchar (255) primary key,
pswd varchar(255) not null, 
email varchar(255) not null,
member_since timestamp default now() not null,
payment_due decimal (6, 2) not null default 0,
)
;
```

Comment: not looks like mysql syntax. do bit google about table creation ddl for mysql

Comment: The `,` before the closing `)`

Comment: @DanielW. thank you!! that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is extra comma at the end.

Just remove it and everything works fine.

```
create table members (
id varchar (255) primary key,
pswd varchar(255) not null, 
email varchar(255) not null,
member_since timestamp default now() not null,
payment_due decimal (6, 2) not null default 0)
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1ae3c0021b4bebdc331c39793d63723)